# SQLite Database File Invalidated from Query Being Interrupted (using DuckDB Python)

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, duckdb

Connected to an SQLite DB file via DuckDB Python DB API in read_only mode. Ran a typical SELECT query, which was interrupted - I believe my python process was closed, I don't remember exactly.

Went to query the DB file again and got the following error message. Restarting the python script and the DB connection, I still get the error message:

> Error: FATAL Error: Failed: database has been invalidated because of a previous fatal error. The database must be restarted prior to being used again.
> Original error: "INTERNAL Error: Catalog entry type"

Not sure the specific version of SQLite it is using, but likely the most recent release around early 2019.

This is my first time using DuckDB, and I very rarely have used SQLite, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may wish to check out https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#busy_snapshot (the only error that includes *invalidate*).